# Invalid argument line 80 in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I already checked coma, semicolon in the code and all seem fine.In Firefox and Chrome it working fine but in IE8 it prompt me Invalid Argument line 80 in Highcharts.js which is point to:

```
if(!C.namespaces.hcv)C.namespaces.add("hcv","urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml")
```

Here is my code

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: container[0],
            type: 'column',
            style: {
                fontFamily: '"Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif"',
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            spacingLeft: 0

        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: null,
        yAxis: {
        title: null,
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: '#505050',
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                step: 1,
                y: 0,
                style: {
                    fontFamily: '"Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif"',
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    fontWeight: 'normal'
                }
            },



            min: 0,
            minRange:0.1

        },
        xAxis: {
            categories:cat,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontFamily: '"Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif"',
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    width: '90px'
                }
            },
            tickWidth: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {

                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {


                        var percent =0;

                        var catName =this.x;

                        if(catName.indexOf('TAM')>=0){
                            percent = this.y ;             
                            if (percent <= 50) {
                                return '<span style="color: #7b4000">' + percent + '</span>';
                            } else {
                                return '<span style="color: #3a5305">' + percent + '</span>';
                            }

                        }

                        else {
                           percent =Math.round( this.point.shareValue * 100)/100;

                            if (percent <= 50) {
                                return '<span style="color: #7b4000">' + percent + '%</span>';
                            } else {
                                return '<span style="color: #3a5305">' + percent + '%</span>';
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    style: {
                        fontFamily: '"Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif"',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    zIndex: 11,
                    useHTML: true
                },
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: data
        }],
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }, function(chart) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            chart.renderer.path(['M', 23, 160.5 - 28 * i, 'L', 34, 160.5 - 28 * i]).attr({
                'stroke-width': 1,
                stroke: 'white',
                'stroke-opacity': 0.7,
                zIndex: 10
            }).add();
            if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version <= 8) && !CHART_CUT_LINE_FOR_IE) {
                continue;
            }
            chart.renderer.path(['M', 30, 160.5 - 28 * i, 'L', 300, 160.5 - 28 * i]).attr({
                'stroke-width': 1,
                stroke: 'white',
                'stroke-opacity': 0.3,
                zIndex: 10
            }).add();
        }
    });
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't provide whole code. Using your chart code, setting up my `categories` and `data`, and including jquery 1.8.3 (`$.browser.msie` is not available from 1.9.0 on) I got chart without error. It'd best to prepare example in jsFiddle.

Comment: please provide full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bumped into this URL: [Highcharts IE issues with jQuery ajax load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895056/highcharts-ie-issues-with-jquery-ajax-load) . I commented the snippet below from my  highcharts.js file

```
,C.createStyleSheet().cssText="hcv\\:fill, hcv\\:path, hcv\\:shape, hcv\\:stroke{ behavior:url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; }
```

It works, now it working in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change that line:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version <= 8) && !CHART_CUT_LINE_FOR_IE) {
            continue;
        }
```

to:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 8 && !CHART_CUT_LINE_FOR_IE) {
            continue;
        }
```